# HTTP 405 Status after reviewing multiple times the URL with Flask

Tags: python, html, flask, http-status-code-302, http-status-code-405

I'm making a simple web app that sends, deletes and edits data to a MariaDB database and I'm using Flask as a framework. Currently, the `app.py` script is fully working except for the editing API, responding a 405 Status. I've already checked my website config and especially the URLs. I checked also the DB config if it allows to change data from the web app and nothing. This is my repo: https://www.github.com/Its-Yayo/f-test

I'm deducing the problem is right here:

```py
@app.route("/edit_contact/<id>", methods=['POST']) # Here
def get_contact(id: int) -> str:
    # FIXME: 405 Method Not Allowed
    conn = connection()
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute('SELECT * FROM contacts WHERE idcontact = %d', (id)) # Or here
    data = cur.fetchall()
    print(data[0]) # Debug Message

    return render_template('edit.html', contact=data[0]) # It doesn't ever render the file
```

I'm expecting a 302 Status that responses the `edit.html` file but seems the URL is wrong. However, the method that deletes data has the same config as in the `index.html` and it works perfectly. I set up the URLs here

```html
{% for contact in contacts %}
     <tr>
            <td>{{ contact.1}}</td>
            <td>{{ contact.2}}</td>
            <td>{{ contact.3}}</td>
            <td>
                <a href='/edit_contact/{{ contact.0 }}'>Edit</a>
                <a href='/delete_contact/{{ contact.0 }}'>Delete</a>
            </td>
     </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

However I'm still troubleshooting to check and fix this error. Any help or PR will be welcomed.

Comment: You're submitting wrong METHOD. That or the server is submitting 405 for some reason. :|

Comment: Looks like you're passing GET requests for a POST API, I would adjust the links and their parameter and pass them as posts with XHR or FETCH.

Comment: Right.  Your tags are submitting with method GET, and you're only looking for POST.